# Why is this code is not working? It is giving me an error of "variable h might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

The following code doesn't pass compilation.
It is giving me this error:

> variable h might not have been initialized

```
public class MnmEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int h; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                if (j == 10) {
                    h = 20; 
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(h); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't analyze your for loops to make sure that `h` is always assigned within them. Therefore it doesn't know if at the point where you attempt to print `h` (`System.out.println(h)`), it has already been assigned.

This can be easily avoided by giving `h` an initial value:

```
int h = 0;
```